# Discord Botnot joining voice channel with no error messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to build a discord music playing bot. For reference purposes I am on

- DiscordJS v14.14.1
- DiscordJS voice 0.16.1
- play-dl 1.9.7

I am using an event driven design system to know when to load a new video however the bot is not joining the voice channel but no error messages are being given. Here is where I try to join the voice channel

```js
events.on(eventNames.PlayNextEvent, async () => {
  logger.logInfo(eventNames.PlayNextEvent);
  const item = await queue.next();

  // establish voice channel connection
  let voiceConnection = getVoiceConnection(item.guildId);
  if (!voiceConnection) {
    logger.logInfo(`creating voice connection in guild ${item.guildId} in channel ${item.voiceChannelId}...`);
    
    let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(item.guildId);
    voiceConnection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: item.voiceChannelId,
      guild: item.guildId,
      adapterCreator: guild.voiceAdapterCreator
    });
  }

  const stream = await audioPlayer.buildStream(item);

  if (!stream) {
    logger.logError('stream is null');
    return;
  }

  const resource = createAudioResource(stream.stream, {
    inputType: stream.type
  });

  let discordPlayer = createAudioPlayer({
    behaviors: {
      noSubscriber: NoSubscriberBehavior.Stop
    }
  });
  discordPlayer.play(resource);
  voiceConnection.subscribe(discordPlayer);
  logger.logInfo(`playing "${item.title}"`);
});
```

I have verified that the event is being called and all the log messages I have in there are being printed. I have also tried having the voice connection and the player be global variables as well but that did not work. I have also confirmed that the `guilId` and `voiceChannelId` i am providing to `joinVoiceChannel` were correct and `guild.voiceAdapterCreator` is not null. Additionally I have initialized my client with the following intents

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
  ]
});
```

For additional reference, here is `buildStream`

```js
exports.buildStream = async (videoInfo) => {
  try {
    return await play.stream(videoInfo.info.url);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.logError('error bulding stream');
    logger.logError(err);
    return null;
  }
};
```

and `const item = await queue.next()` returns an item from a queue in mongodb which i confirmed is working and saving all the info i need correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this problem, I have the guild id variable name in joinVoiceChannel wrong. I just had guild when it should have been guildId.

```
voiceConnection = joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: item.voiceChannelId,
  guildId: item.guildId,
  adapterCreator: guild.voiceAdapterCreator
});
```